# MYSQL request | GROUP BY DAY

Tags: php, mysql, request, grouping

I have a table: orders, and need to make a request and get other table.
My DB table:

```
id  close
1   2012-05-29 03:11:15
2   2012-05-30 03:11:40
3   2012-05-31 03:12:10
4   2012-05-31 03:14:13
5   2012-05-31 03:16:50
6   2012-05-31 03:40:07     
7   2012-05-31 05:22:18
8   2012-05-31 05:22:22
9   2012-05-31 05:22:50
...
```

I need to make a request and get this table (GROUP BY DAY(close)):

```
1   2012-05-29 03:11:15
2   2012-05-30 03:11:40
9   2012-05-31 05:22:50 /*This is a last record on this day (05-31)*/
```

Thanks!

If I make this request:

```
SELECT id, close
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY DAY(close)
ORDER BY id ASC
```

I will get this table:

```
1   2012-05-29 03:11:15
2   2012-05-30 03:11:40
3   2012-05-31 03:12:10
```

Comment: This is the third question you've asked on this topic...

Comment: My question is: how can I get this table from request: 1   2012-05-29 03:11:15
2   2012-05-30 03:11:40
9   2012-05-31 05:22:50 /*This is a last record on this day (05-31)*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this will do.

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.close
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        id,
        close
    FROM
        `orders`
    ORDER BY
        close DESC
) AS a
GROUP BY 
    DATE(a.close)
ORDER BY 
    a.id
ASC;
```

Comment: @user889349 I'd recommend to read [12.16.3. `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) especially: *The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, **the values chosen are indeterminate**. Furthermore, **the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause**. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.*. It's silly to rely on luck in the RDBMS world :-).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select t1.* 
from orders t1
join (
    select max(close) as close
    from orders
    group by date(close)
) t2 on t1.close = t2.close
```

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e799a/1

Comment: @user889349 `tab` was table name for test only, now I've changed it to `orders`. `t1` and `t2` are table aliases more about it is there: [SQL Alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).

Comment: @user889349 I wonder why have you removed "acceptance" from my answer? especially that there is no guarantee that sephoy08 query always returns correct result set. More on ['MySQL `group by`'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html): *The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, **the values chosen are indeterminate***.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help:

```sql
SELECT temp.`close`
FROM (
SELECT `close`
FROM `orders`
ORDER BY `close` DESC
) AS temp
ORDER BY `close` ASC
```