# cumulative sum grouped by day

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, average

I have this table:

```
id
entry_date (timestamp)
exit_date (timestamp)
```

I need to show the cumulative difference per every day. Actually average, but let at least be just cumulative.

So the output will look like this:

```
2015 1 1 33
2015 1 3 56
2015 2 4 77
2015 3 12 123
```

Meaning

```
Year month day cummulative_sum(exit_date-entry_date).
```

I have checked similar threads:

[MySQL cumulative sum grouped by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276790/mysql-cumulative-sum-grouped-by-date)

[Cumulative sum over a set of rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664436/cumulative-sum-over-a-set-of-rows-in-mysql)

[Optimal query to fetch a cumulative sum in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144766/optimal-query-to-fetch-a-cumulative-sum-in-mysql)

[Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

[MYSQL request | GROUP BY DAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831941/mysql-request-group-by-day)

But none of the solutions worked for me. I am becoming desperate to do this with SQL alone.
But the tasks sounds so simple that it's hard to believe the solution is a difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to work something more efficient but I believe this is something to get you going. And your explanation is not incredible clear so you might want to work on providing some sample data to clarify what you need.

```
select
    event_date,
    (
        select sum(+1) from T as t2 where cast(t2.entry_date as date) <= d.event_date +
        select sum(-1) from T as t3 where cast(t3.exit_date  as date) <= d.event_date
    ) as cumulative_total /* at end of day */
from (
    select cast(entry_date as date) as event_date from T union all
    select cast(exit_date  as date) from T
) as d
group by event_date
```

*Replace T with the name of your table. Also I used a cast to strip away the time but I'm not sure that's actually valid in MySQL.*

The average of days (not including any dates not represented by an entry or exit) is then easy as well:

```
select avg(cumulative_total) as average_per_day
from (
    select
        (
            select sum(+1) from T as t2 where cast(t2.entry_date as date) <= d.event_date +
            select sum(-1) from T as t3 where cast(t3.exit_date  as date) <= d.event_date
        ) as cumulative_total /* at end of day */
    from (
        select cast(entry_date as date) as event_date from T union all
        select cast(exit_date  as date) from T
    ) as d
    group by event_date
) as d2
```